# boost library path

Tags: c++, boost

I built the boost library, and I see that some libraries appear more than once within boost filesystem. For example, regex can be found either under boost/bin.v2/..../link-static or boost/bin.v2/..../threading-multi.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it matters. How much depends on your platform (some platform have auto-linking to determine which version of the library to link to, e.g. Visual C++)

The explanation of the naming conventions can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming). I'd reccommend going through that whole page carefully, it'll save you grief later on...